# Custom font in navigation bar using supersonic

Tags: android, css, hybrid-mobile-app, steroids, supersonic

I am quite new (read absolute beginner) to mobile development using hybrid framework. For my first project I decided to use the Supersonic framework by AppGyver. The problem occured, when I wanted to change the font of title in navigation bar. Here's what I tried:

I put downloaded font-related files into folder `appName/app/common/assets/fonts`.

Afterwards I created a stylesheet, that contains "custom" font definition:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ralewaybold';
src: url('/fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('/fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('/fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('/fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('/fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('/fonts/raleway-bold-webfont.svg#ralewaybold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

saved it into raleway.css (here, I need to say, that I tried to put this code into android.css and application.css files, but none of those worked.)

Finally, I wanted to change the font of navigation bar title of default application (created by `steroids create appName`) by editing

`navigation-bar title {
...
font-family: "ralewaybold";}`

but nothing happenned.

As I said in beginning I am quite new to hybrid development (and stuff around it), so I will appreciate very much, if you'd advice anything that would help me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some trouble with Fonts in Android like yours. Simply as that: some Fonts work some dont and it doesnt matter if it is ttf or somewhat else supported.

You can jsut check if it doesnt work with other fonts. If one Font doesnt work Android just uses the default font Android Sans...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Can u describe how did u apply any font into supersonic app? I still can't find out how to do that properly. Thanks